# Jquery Hide & Show according to Class Names

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am wrinting a jquery to hide and show the `<li>` according to the class name exists. In `<li>` tag i am creating a class name based on the php results. here is my code

```
<?php 
foreach($xxx as $yyy) 
{
    if($yyy['cod'] == 1){ $codClass = 'codEnabled'; } 
    if($yyy['emi'] == 1){ $emiClass = 'emiEnabled'; } 
    if($yyy['stock'] == 1){ $stockClass = 'in_stock'; } 
    if($yyy['shipping'] == 1){ $shipClass = 'freeShipping'; }     
    ?>
    <li class="minclass <?php echo $codClass.' '.$emiClass.' '.$stockClass.' '.$shipClass; ?>">
    {my data}
    </li>
<?php } ?>

<span class="filteroptions" id="shippingfree" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #0461AA;color: #5E5E5E;cursor: pointer;">Free Shipping</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;

<span class="filteroptions" id="stock"style="border-bottom: 2px solid #0461AA;color: #5E5E5E;cursor: pointer;">In Stock</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;

<span class="filteroptions" id="emi" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #0461AA;color: #5E5E5E;cursor: pointer;">EMI</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;

<span class="filteroptions" id='cod' style="border-bottom: 2px solid #0461AA;color: #5E5E5E;cursor: pointer;">COD</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;

<span class="filteroptions" id="reset" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #0461AA;color: #5E5E5E;cursor: pointer;">Reset All
```

### SAMPLE HTML OUTPUT

```
Filters : Freeshipping  | In Stock | COD | EMI | Reset All


    <li class="mainclass pricevariant codEnabled emiEnabled in_stock freeShipping"> {mydata} </li>
<li class="mainclass pricevariant codEnabled emiEnabled in_stock freeShipping non-variant"> {mydata} </li>
    <li class="mainclass pricevariant in_stock freeShipping"> {mydata} </li>
    <li class="mainclass pricevariant in_stock freeShipping non-variant"> {mydata} </li>
    <li class="mainclass pricevariant codEnabled in_stock freeShipping non-variant"> {mydata} </li>
    <li class="mainclass pricevariant codEnabled freeShipping"> {mydata} </li>
    <li class="mainclass pricevariant codEnabled in_stock"> {mydata} </li>
    <li class="mainclass pricevariant codEnabled emiEnabled in_stock freeShipping"> {mydata} </li>
    <li class="mainclass pricevariant freeShipping"> {mydata} </li>
    <li class="mainclass pricevariant in_stock emiEnabled freeShipping"> {mydata} </li>
```

Here is my Jquery Script

```
$('.filteroptions').click(function(){

    var myid = (event.target.id);
    //
    //var productNamee = '<?php echo $proname; ?>';
    //
    if (myid !='')
    {
        if (myid=='cod') {
            $('.pricevariant').slideToggle('slow');

            $('.non-variant').slideToggle('slow');
        }
        if (myid =='shippingfree') {
            $('.pricevariant').slideToggle('slow');
            $('.freeShipping').slideToggle('slow');
            $('.non-variant').slideToggle('slow');
        }
        if (myid =='stock') {

            $('.freeShipping').hide('slow');
            $('.codEnabled').hide('slow');
            $('.non-variant').slideToggle('slow');
            $('.in_stock').slideToggle('slow');
            $('.pricevariant').slideToggle('slow');
        }
    }


});
```

What is the problem i am facing here is if *'free shipping'* is clicked first time it is shwoing , the second click i fire on *'cod'* it is not showing only cod , the third click i fire on any filter option then all the list results are hide

Comment: None of your example `LI`s have class `pricevariant` or `non-variant`.  So clicking on `cod` doesn't do anything.

Comment: I've made a fiddle with your sample code, but I can't tell from your question what the correct behavior is: http://jsfiddle.net/dS2w9/

Comment: @Barmar i had updated my full code

Comment: @Barmar i updated your fiddle too. http://jsfiddle.net/dS2w9/3/

Comment: @Raaga See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/dS2w9/4/), and I also solved it in my answer too.

Comment: @RohanKumar i check your code . First Click free shipping , 2nd click , in stock , 3rd click COD , and check the result <li>10</li> doesn't have codEnabled. 'This kind of problem only i am facing'

Comment: But it has `class pricevariant` and see your condition `if (myid=='cod') {`.

Comment: @RohanKumar see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dS2w9/5/) now. updated the code. On the very first click on Free shipping <li>7</li> is showing

Comment: Use `$('.mainclass').hide();` before slideToggle See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/dS2w9/6/);

Comment: @RohanKumar . The code is working Now. Thanks . But the below answer u  submitted i didn't try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make other classes as blank in your `$xxx` loop like,

```
<?php
  foreach($xxx as $yyy)  {
      // make all classes as blank, if previously added.
      $codClass ='';$emiClass ='';$stockClass ='';$shipClass ='';
      if($yyy['cod'] == 1){ $codClass = 'codEnabled'; } 
      if($yyy['emi'] == 1){ $emiClass = 'emiEnabled'; } 
      if($yyy['stock'] == 1){ $stockClass = 'in_stock'; } 
      if($yyy['shipping'] == 1){ $shipClass = 'freeShipping'; } 
      ....
```

One more thing if you see in your `console`, then you'll find an error 'event is not defined', so to remove this add a parameter `event` in your click callback like,

```
$('.filteroptions').click(function(event){
        // -----add event here ----^
     var myid = (event.target.id);
              // --^-- here you are using event, which is undefined
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/n5GC6/)

**Alternatively,** I think this code cane be short by using `data-atrrribute` for example if you add all classes which you want to slide then add in your `span element` with `data-` like,

```
<span data-classes=".pricevariant,.freeShipping,.non-variant"
     class="filteroptions" id='shippingfree' >Free Shipping</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;
....
```

And in **Script** try it like,

```
$(function(){
    $('.filteroptions').click(function(){
        $('.mainclass').hide();// hide all li first(let mainclass is common in li's)
        $($(this).data('classes')).slideToggle();// now toggle only selected classes
    });
});
```

Hope the above will work for you.

Comment: I don't think that's his problem. Look at his sample output, the second `LI` doesn't have all the classes from the first `LI`. I suspect he just didn't copy that line to SO.

Comment: May be he is not showing his full code, but if all classes are applied in the first cycle of loop then all li will have the same class. And the show/hide will not work properly. Right?

Comment: That's would be correct. This was the first thing I thought of when reading his code, but then I saw the sample output. It doesn't have all the classes from the first line repeated in the other lines.

Comment: @Raaga try my alternative option, once.